# While loop indentation is messing with my variables

Tags: python, while-loop, indentation

I'm very new to programming and I have a piece of code that works one way, but only works semi-correctly in two other ways. I simply want to understand why.
This is from a text game that I am following:

```
while current_scene != last_scene:
        next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
        current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

current_scene.enter()
```

this piece of code works correctly, however, I thought that indenting current_scene.enter() would appropriately make it part of the while loop, as shown below

```
while current_scene != last_scene:
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
    current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

    current_scene.enter()
```

In other parts of my code, the scenes contain input. When this line is indented to be part of the while loop, what happens is when you give the correct input, it goes through the same scene again. Giving it the correct input a second time finally allows it to continue with the rest of the game. Why does this happen?

Lastly, if I move current_scene.enter() above the while loop, it repeats the first scene twice after the correct input, why is that?
below is what it looks like

```
current_scene.enter()
while current_scene != last_scene:
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
    current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

I appreciate any and all help. This is my first question on StackOverflow and I apologize if I did this incorrectly.

Comment: "however, I thought that indenting current_scene.enter() would appropriately make it part of the while loop" - it would make it part of the while loop, but *appropriately*? No. That call is not supposed to be inside the loop.

Comment: In the second one, you're executing `current_scene.enter()` every iteration of the `while` loop. Not sure what your desired behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like current_scene.enter() returns the next scene name and you need to call  current_scene.enter() on the final scene to roll credits.

```
while current_scene != last_scene:
        current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(current_scene.enter())

current_scene.enter()
```

perhaps the logic makes sense without the extra variable. Although the "extra variable" might be necessary because `scene_map.next_scene(...)` might not return the next scene name like `current_scene.enter()` does.